# How to fit child div within parent div width while keeping absolute positioning?

Tags: html, css

I am building a web page for homework. I have this issue where my child div is expanding more than its parent div in width.

So I want my child div which is called `<div class="dropdown-content">` to have absolute positioning because it makes the child div overlap the parent div which is called `<div class="box">`. However the child div has width not relative to the width of the parent.

I tried position: relative on `<div class="dropdown-content">` but all parent divs expand when hovered over to make the child div overlap the parent.

So how do I make the child div overlap the parent while simultaneously keeping the width of the parent div?

Link to the web page: http://techteach.us/Web2020/ZWeiJian/WCP/Labs/Lab_01/Lb1Labs.html

```css
/*For each individual box.*/
.box{
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-width: 20%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

/*Creates the styling of the dropdown box.*/
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #62ff36;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(56, 255, 42, 0.8);
  padding-top: 12px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.inside-box:hover .dropdown-content {
 display: block; 
}
```

```html
<!--Each individual box.-->
     <div class="box">

    <!--The box inside each individual box. Think of it as like bubble wrap inside a box.-->
    <div class="inside-box" onMouseOver="showDDContent();" onMouseOut="hideDDContent();">

      <!--The div with an image in it. Top one inside the box div.-->
      <div>
     <a href="Lab_01/LB1_WeiJianZhen_DD.html">
      <!--Get an image with 300px width by 200px height. Make it responsive.-->
      <img src="../../../Visual Content/placeholder.jpg" alt="Under Contruction" class="imgGrids">
     </a>
      </div>

      <!--The div that contains the heading or title of the lab.-->
      <div class="txtBar">
       <h3><a href="Lab_01/LB1_WeiJianZhen_DD.html">Lab 1</a></h3>
      </div>

      <!--The div that drops down to explain the lab with some text.-->
      <div class="dropdown-content">
     <p>My first website ever made in an HTML file! Describes a bit about the process of making a very basic website like mine.</p>
      </div>

    <!--End of inside box div.-->
    </div>

     <!--End of box div.-->
     </div>

<!--Lab 2-->
     <!--Each individual box.-->
     <div class="box">

    <!--The box inside each individual box. Think of it as like bubble wrap inside a box.-->
    <div class="inside-box" onMouseOver="showDDContent();" onMouseOut="hideDDContent();">

      <!--The div with an image in it. Top one inside the box div.-->
      <div>
     <a href="Lab_02/LB2_WeiJianZhen_DD.html">
      <img src="../../../Visual Content/placeholder.jpg" alt="Under Contruction" class="imgGrids">
       </a>
      </div>

      <!--The div that contains the heading or title of the lab.-->
      <div class="txtBar">
       <h3><a href="Lab_02/LB2_WeiJianZhen_DD.html">Lab 2</a></h3>
      </div>

      <!--The div that drops down to explain the lab with some text.-->
      <div class="dropdown-content">
     <p>
      This webpage describes a bit about myself and my aspirations about programming/web designer. Has an image of me too.
     </p>
      </div>

    <!--End of inside box div.-->
    </div>

     <!--End of box div.-->
     </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a `width:100%` on your `dropdown-content` class and a `position:relative` on `box` to ensure it's the width of this parent that's selected.

By default, the absolute element will fit its content.

Comment: No problem, good luck with your homework. :) Btw, if you want to add a simple and sweet fresh touch on your page, you could utilize a css-gradient. There are plenty of useful presets here : https://uigradients.com